# SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync always fails after I changed from LocalDB to a SQL database

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

So when I initially sign in with Google in my test MVC app, I register, my credentials are saved in the SQL database, and I am signed in just fine. But when I sign out and try to sign back in with the same Gmail account, the program doesn't recognize that I'm trying to sign in with a username that is already registered in the database - so it prompts me back in to the register page, where obviously I can't register because the account is already registered.

This only happened when I switched over from the local db to a SQL db. Everything was working fine on the local database.

Could anyone be so kind as to lend a little guidance? It would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. I missed something in the Create Table query for the AspNetUsers table. All works well!